# Non-integer ids in Spark MLlib ALS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'd like to use

```
val ratings = data.map(_.split(',') match {
      case Array(user,item,rate)
      =>
        Rating(user.toInt,item.toInt,rate.toFloat)
    })
val model =  ALS.train(ratings,rank,numIterations,alpha)
```

However, the user data i get are stored as Long. When switched to int, it may produce error. 
How can i do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of  ML implementations which support `Long` labels. `RDD` version it is significantly less user friendly compared to other implementations:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating

val ratings = sc.parallelize(Seq(Rating(1L, 2L, 3.0f), Rating(2L, 3L, 5.0f)))

val (userFactors, itemFactors) = ALS.train(ratings)
```

and returns only factors but `DataFrame` version returns a model:

```
val ratingsDF= ratings.toDF

val alsModel = new ALS().fit(ratingsDF)
```

Comment: Here, if the user and item values are String, will it work? In what format should the string be?

Comment: I tried the above example with user and item value as String. and I am getting the exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 0 in null`, when I do the `.fit(ratingsDF)`